# Pandas Produce a dataframe with range of value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
speciality_id   speciality_name
1               Acupuncturist
2               Andrologist
3               Anaesthesiologist
4               Audiologist
5               Ayurvedic Doctor
6               Biochemist
7               Biophysicist
```

I want to copy the above dataframe for a range of value, year and month.

For example:

```
year = [2018]
Month = [1,2]
```

I want to produce a dataframe like the following:

```
Year    Month   speciality_id   speciality_name
2018    1       1               Acupuncturist
2018    1       2               Andrologist
2018    1       3               Anaesthesiologist
2018    1       4               Audiologist
2018    1       5               Ayurvedic Doctor
2018    1       6               Biochemist
2018    1       7               Biophysicist

2018    2       1               Acupuncturist
2018    2       2               Andrologist
2018    2       3               Anaesthesiologist
2018    2       4               Audiologist
2018    2       5               Ayurvedic Doctor
2018    2       6               Biochemist
2018    2       7               Biophysicist
```

I am unable to think of an approach. What is the right way to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `product` for all combinations, create `DataFrame` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
year = [2018]
Month = [1,2]

from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(year, Month, df['speciality_id'])), 
                   columns=['Year','Month','speciality_id'])
print (df1)
    Year  Month  speciality_id
0   2018      1              1
1   2018      1              2
2   2018      1              3
3   2018      1              4
4   2018      1              5
5   2018      1              6
6   2018      1              7
7   2018      2              1
8   2018      2              2
9   2018      2              3
10  2018      2              4
11  2018      2              5
12  2018      2              6
13  2018      2              7
```

---

```
df = df1.merge(df, on='speciality_id', how='left')
print (df)
    Year  Month  speciality_id    speciality_name
0   2018      1              1      Acupuncturist
1   2018      1              2        Andrologist
2   2018      1              3  Anaesthesiologist
3   2018      1              4        Audiologist
4   2018      1              5   Ayurvedic Doctor
5   2018      1              6         Biochemist
6   2018      1              7       Biophysicist
7   2018      2              1      Acupuncturist
8   2018      2              2        Andrologist
9   2018      2              3  Anaesthesiologist
10  2018      2              4        Audiologist
11  2018      2              5   Ayurvedic Doctor
12  2018      2              6         Biochemist
13  2018      2              7       Biophysicist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the Cartesian product via [`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), then join with a tiled dataframe:

```
year = [2018]
month = [1, 2]

# calculate Cartesian product and repeat by number of rows in dataframe
cart_prod = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([year, month], names=['year', 'month'])

# tile dataframe and join year_month index
res = df.loc[np.tile(df.index, len(year) * len(month))]\
        .set_index(cart_prod.repeat(df.shape[0])).reset_index()

print(res)

    year  month  speciality_id    speciality_name
0   2018      1              1      Acupuncturist
1   2018      1              2        Andrologist
2   2018      1              3  Anaesthesiologist
3   2018      1              4        Audiologist
4   2018      1              5    AyurvedicDoctor
5   2018      1              6         Biochemist
6   2018      1              7       Biophysicist
7   2018      2              1      Acupuncturist
8   2018      2              2        Andrologist
9   2018      2              3  Anaesthesiologist
10  2018      2              4        Audiologist
11  2018      2              5    AyurvedicDoctor
12  2018      2              6         Biochemist
13  2018      2              7       Biophysicist
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope can help you with this.

```
# A: Create the new columns
df['Year'], df['Month'] = 2018, None 

# A: Create the two new DataFrame
df1 = df.copy()
df2 = df.copy()

# A: Edith the month in both DataFrames
df1['Month'], df2['Month'] = 1, 2
```